# How I can give a link to the caption of audio post on the wall

Tags: facebook

Hey!! I have made an application through which I am publishing an audio file to the wall in facebook. Further I want to give a clickable caption, that when get a click take me to some url. Can somebdy plz help me in sorting it out....

Thanx in advance...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send media as an attachment with your publish request.

```
{"media": [{
    "type": "music", 
    "src": "URL_OF_MEDIA", 
    "title": "NAME_OF_AUDIO_CLIP", 
    "artist": "ARTIST", 
    "album": "ALBUM"
}]}
```

Docs here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments

Comment: Darren I think you didn't get me, my question is how to make a clickable caption with my audio that I am publishing through my application. I have already completed the task to publish audio on facebook.